# PHPUnit signals a warning when mocking a namespace-ed class

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader, phpunit

My composer project consists of the `src` and `tests` folders.
The code inside `src` is auto-loaded using composers psr4 autoloader like so

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "christmas\\":"src/"
    }
}
```

The class to be tested looks like so

```
namespace christmas;
class Hello
{   //constructor & dependency injection included in real class

public function sayHello()
{
    return "HELLO";
}
}
```

And Finally my test class looks like so

```
<?php
    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
    require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
    use christmas\Hello;


    class TestHello extends TestCase
    {
        public function testSayHelloMethod()
        {
            $hello = $this->getMockBuilder('Hello')
                ->getMock();
            $hello->expects($this->once())
                ->method('sayHello')
                ->will($this->returnValue('HELLO'));

            $this->assertEquals(
                "HELLO",
                $hello->sayHello()
            );


        }
    }
```

And here is how my i run phpunit

```
phpunit tests/TestHello
```

phpunit echoes back the following output

```
Time: 45 ms, Memory: 4.00 MB

    There was 1 warning:

    1) tests\Hello::testSayHelloMethod()
    Trying to configure method "sayHello" which cannot be configured because it does not exist, has not been specified, is final, or is static

    /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:641
    /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:206
    /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:162

    WARNINGS!
    Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Warnings: 1.
```

Below is a view of how my code is organized,

```
    ├── composer.json
    ├── src
    │   └── Hello.php
    ├── tests
    │   └── TestHello.php
    └── vendor
```

What am i missing ? I need to have a passing test with no single warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the full, namespaced name of the class to the mock builder, i.e. `'christmas\Hello'`.  Since you need to pass it as a string, just using "Hello" isn't enough to properly identify the class.

Since you're already have a `use` for the class, you can use `::class` to get the full name.  For example:

```
$hello = $this->getMockBuilder(Hello::class)
                ->getMock();
```

Comment: thanks @Peter , adding full namespace works `christmas\Hello` and `Hello::class` also works perfectly. Thanks!!!